# lodash _.remove not working on an object content

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, lodash

I can't have lodash _.remove to work in an object content that looks like this

```
content: { 
 code: '8d303377',
 type: 'content',
 repositoryCode: 'default',
 externalLocations: 
  { 
   binaries: 
    { 
      medium: 'http://localhost:4000/image-medium.jpg',
      small: '' 
    } 
  } 
 }
```

and I would like to remove the entry with empty string (small). I tried this

```
 _.remove(content.externalLocations.binaries, function () {
     return content.externalLocations.binaries[req.params.variant] === req.body.url;
 });
```

The value of *req.params.variant == small*

I tried also this

```
_.forEach(content.externalLocations, function (binary) {
    _.remove(binary[req.params.variant], { [req.params.variant]: req.body.url });
});
```

Comment: The `content:..` block in your code doesn't seems to be a valid JSON.

Comment: binaries should be array other wise if you want to delete from json object only the use delete obj.binares.somekey

Comment: My bad not json a js object

Comment: As Jayant said _remove requires an array https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks like you are trying to delete entries from `binaries` whose values are equal to `req.body.url`, you can do:

```
_.each(content.externalLocations.binaries, (value, key, obj) => {
    if (req.params.variant === key && req.body.url === value) {
      _.unset(obj, key);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `_.remove` states

> Removes all elements from **array**  that predicate returns truthy for and returns an array of the removed elements [...]
>   <sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

Your `binaries` object is not an array.If you want to remove an object property use `delete`

```
delete content.externalLocations.binaries[req.params.variant];
```

```js
var content = { 
 code: '8d303377',
 type: 'content',
 repositoryCode: 'default',
 externalLocations: 
  { 
   binaries: 
    { 
      medium: 'http://localhost:4000/image-medium.jpg',
      small: '' 
    } 
  } 
 };

delete content.externalLocations.binaries.small;

console.log(content)
```